# Teamcity control application deploy?

Tags: java, tomcat, teamcity

Could Teamcity control application deploy, for example to tomcat?

P.S. without plugins like [this](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/Deployer+plugin)

Comment: Why don't you want to use a plugin?

Comment: Just curios, why teamcity doesn't have own functionality for deployment process...

Comment: is autoDeploy turned on?  I would think you could just have a command line task that copies the .war over to the appBase, right?

Answer (score 0):

We implemented similar tasks with Teamcity to deploy war files to our jetty servers:

- After the ordinary build step that creates the war file, we invoke a
  script in a "**Command Line**" build step which uses scp to copy the war
  file to the jetty server.
- On the jetty server, there is a **cron job** running at every five
  minutes just checking if there is a new war file or not. If there is,
  it shutdowns down jetty server, backs up the existing war file and
  put the new war file, then start up jetty server again.

One drawback of the solution above is that after Teamcity build finishes, we always need to wait some time until the cron job kicks in and redeploys the war.

There is a slightly different approach, which can deploy war file in the Teamcity build process:

Instead of using a cron job to invoke the deployment script, it can be invoked from that "Command Line" build step also, by something like following, after "scp" finishes copying the war file.

```
ssh -t user@server: "path_to_the_deployment_script"
```

We have never tried the second approach yet, theoretically it should work.