# How to deploy java .war file to Linux server from TeamCity after build?

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, deployment, teamcity

We have a Java web service project that is checked into GitHub. We have a corresponding project in TeamCity that pulls the files from GitHub. TeamCity compiles the project and produces the deployable .war file as an artifact.

Today TeamCity stops there and just sits on the artifact. Normally I deploy the war file through the built-in Apache management window on the :8080 port. However, I'd like to have TeamCity perform this deploy automatically after a successful build.

The TeamCity build server is on a Windows machine, the Apache machine is Linux. The war file is deployed to the /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps folder.

So my question boils down to the following: how can I set up TeamCity so that it takes the war file and copies it over to /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps on a different machine?

We have similar projects where TeamCity deploys a .NET project to another Windows server using psake scripts, i.e. it's Windows-to-Windows file transfer. Can psake be used to transfer files to Linux as well?

I have been considering solutions such as Puppet and Putty, but I don't know where to start really.

Any suggestions are welcome,
Andras

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a solution that uses SCP and SSH to allow TeamCity to copy the war file to the Tomcat server and then run some custom bash scripts to finish up the deploy.

Similar to this proposed solution.

[Teamcity control application deploy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15591078/teamcity-control-application-deploy)

Currently running into SSH problems but should get them worked out soon.

There is also the option of using the Tomcat Management capabilities to upload a the war file.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Deploy_A_New_Application_Remotely

I've had this working in test environments using curl to make the request.